# Why is Img tag doesnt work on some spesific URLs

Tags: html, web

I create a web app that shows 320px instagram profile pictures. The app succesfully gathers the pictures link but it doesnt work on html img tag.
for example:

```
<img src="https://instagram.fadb6-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/44329317_268583430479565_454483638147350528_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fadb6-4.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=7Z61E66z1IsAX_UzdtY&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=28b797158b3ae140bc95b94a3f3f138b&oe=61263223&_nc_sid=7bff83">
```

ı dont know why is that and what to do. Are there alternative ways to show a picture on html site?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it would be because of the data behind the .jpg extension of the image. This part to be specific:

```
?_nc_ht=instagram.fadb6-4.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=7Z61E66z1IsAX_UzdtY&edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=28b797158b3ae140bc95b94a3f3f138b&oe=61263223&_nc_sid=7bff83
```

It could also be that you don't have access to the image.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `src` must recive an file url, this url will not work